# increment in for loop of c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

Well I never tried this with for loop. I want to increment the for loop by 8 not general post increment. I am trying something like this.

```
for(U8 i=3;i<=31;i+8,j++){
    Array[j]=(Status>>i) ;

    if (j>3){
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Well it gives me the warning like **left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect**. What is the meaning of this warning? Will my logic work? status contains the 32 bit information of my system and i need particular bit out of that.

Comment: will it increment the value of i by 8 everytime in the loop? sorry for asking silly questions

Comment: If you only need one bit out of Status, use a bit mask https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

Comment: I need 3,11,19 and 27th bit

Comment: `i+8` doesn't result in any change anywhere. Perhaps you meant `i+=8`

Comment: `i+8` doesn't increment `i`; it just returns the (current) value of `i` plus `8`. `i` itself doesn't change. You want `i+=8`, which actually changes the value of `i`.

Comment: I would like to know the reason of so many downvotes here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the literal question as stated...

The reason for the warning is simply because the left side of the comma in the for loop, third section, will have no effect. `i+8` does not change anything, but rather returns a value.

Instead, you are wanting the compound assignment addition operator, `+=` `i+=8`, which will add 8 to the current value of `i`. ([See the Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/))

```
for(U8 i=3;i<=31;i+=8,j++){
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comment "will it increment the value of i by 8 everytime in the loop?"

`i+8` has no effect on `i`,
change it to `i+=8`